# Using paramiko, renaming a file and changing directory fails. Why?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have to process a file on an SFTP server and, when done, move that file to an archive directory using Paramiko. However, if the file already exists in the archive directory, I want to rename the file at the same time. I have the basics for detecting the existing file in archive and adjusting the name. Basically, the final call looks like:

```
client.rename('/main-path/file.txt', '/main-path/archive/file_1.txt')
```

or

```
client.posix_rename('/main-path/file.txt', '/main-path/archive/file_1.txt')
```

These commands work on SOME servers with no problem. On other servers, I get an "Errno 2" error from paramiko.

Am I going about this wrong? Maybe I need to rename the file, in place, first?

```
client.rename('/main-path/file.txt', '/main-path/file_1.txt')
```

and then

```
client.rename('/main-path/file_1.txt', '/main-path/archive/file_1.txt')
```

???

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: btw: when I don't have to rename the file itself, I NEVER have a problem. It's only when I rename the file AND change the path that I get errors.

Comment: Looking at the paramiko source code if a file does not exist I would expect to see an error message in a form of IOError: [Errno 2] Errno 2. In any case, error 2 is ENOENT which is No such file or directory.

Can you post the entire traceback you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file exist by using OS

```
import os

list_element= os.listdir("/main-path/archive")

if "file.txt" in list_element:
   client.posix_rename('/main-path/file.txt', '/main-path/archive/file_1.txt')
else:
   client.posix_rename('/main-path/file.txt', '/main-path/archive/file.txt')
```